# Using if statement in array.forEach function statement to choose sub-object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, node-red

I cannot get an if statement to work inside a function called by a forEach array loop.

I have an array with objects, (with an object)

```
arrofobj = [   
{"thing_id":"1a", "val": 1, "Type": "Switch","ValType":{"0":"Open","1":"Closed"}},  
{"thing_id":"1b", "val": 72, "Type": "Sensor","ValType":{"0":"%"}}]
```

I would like to test if the `Type` is a switch, in order to write info in a new field of the objects of the array `CatX`:
- when it is, I want to use the `val` value to determine which `ValType` element to use in a new variable of array `arrofobj`.
- if not, I want to use the arrofobj.ValType.0 value

```
const getCat = function(){
    if(arrofobj.Type !== 'Switch') 
        arrofobj.ValType'.0' 
    } else {
        arrofobj.ValType.(arrofobj.val)
};

arrofobj.forEach(p => p.CatX = getCat() );
```

I am not getting the lint to accept the code, so cannot test.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Please include them in the question. If you've quoted your source code exactly, I'm guessing that it's to do with the mismatched braces around your `else`.

Comment: Thank you @HarryCutts, to tell you the truth, I have tried many different options, with many varied problems, from lint complaining, to no output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You have to use bracket notation to access properties as strings.

2) You have to close the brackets on if/else correctly.

3) You have to return something from inside getCat to have something to assign to p.CatX

4) You have to actually send the object to getCat inside the loop.

```js
const arrofobj = [   
  {"thing_id":"1a", "val": 1, "Type": "Switch","ValType":{"0":"Open","1":"Closed"}},  
  {"thing_id":"1b", "val": 72, "Type": "Sensor","ValType":{"0":"%"}}
];
const getCat = function( obj ){
    if(obj.Type !== 'Switch') {
        return obj.ValType[ '0' ]
    } else {
        return obj.ValType[ obj.val ];
    }
};

arrofobj.forEach(p => {
  p.CatX = getCat(p);
}); 

console.log( arrofobj );
```

Comment: Thank you @Shilly, it works! All 4 points you gave me I did not know, spent a day already, another day would not have taught me that. I have learnt a great deal today !

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Shilly's answer:

1) In the long-run, if this is data you're creating yourself and not something from a 3rd-party endpoint, you'll find standardising the format of your object property key names (in camelCase) to be easier to work with. It won't introduce as many bugs to your code if they're identically formatted.

2) You can use object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to shorten the code footprint a little.

```js
const arrofobj = [
  { id: '1a', val: 1, type: 'Switch', valType: { '0': 'Open', '1': 'Closed' } },
  { id: '1b', val: 72, type: 'Sensor', valType: { '0': '%' } }
];

function getCat(obj) {

  // Deconstruct the properties from obj
  const { type, valType, val } = obj;

  // Use a ternary operator to decide what to return
  return type === 'Switch' ? valType[val] : valType['0'];
}

arrofobj.forEach(obj => {
   obj.catX = getCat(obj);
});

console.log(arrofobj);
```

Comment: Wow, this is so clean ! Thank you @Andy, going implement this !

Comment: Thanks. Make sure you understand how it works/read through that documentation though.

Comment: Providing that the val will always be an integer, another 'upgrade' would be to use an array instead of an object as valType: `valType: [ "Open", "Closed" ]`. This will make looping easier if you ever need it. You could also use `.map()` over `.forEach()` to do everything in one statement if getCat won't be shared. You could also already add the property catX with value null already so the object structure stays the same.

Comment: I had the same thought, @shilly, but decided against it in the end because the ordering might be an issue.

Comment: Thank you @Shilly, you are thinking ahead if what will catch me in the future, will try some of them.